# Java Polymorphism Compile time and Run time

Tags: java

I have codes like this

```
package test;

public interface X {
    public void m();

}
```

```
package test;

public interface Y {
    public void m();
}
```

```
package test;

public abstract class A implements X{
    public void m(){
        System.out.println("Class A: m");
    }
    abstract  void m2();
}
```

```
package test;

public class B extends  A implements Y{
    public void m2(){
        System.out.println("Class B m2");
    }

    public void m(){
        System.out.println("Class B m");
    }
}
```

```
package test;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Y y = new B(); y.m();
}}
```

So, the main method should print "Class B m" because run time y.m() should point to the class B method m.

However, I am wonder what class' method should y.m() targets to in compile time? Is it interface x method m or interface Y method m?

Because class B extends A which has the method B and implements X that has method B.Then, class B also implements Y that also has method B.

Comment: How can it be `X.m`? `y` is of type `Y`, which is totally unrelated to `X`. What `y` actually stores does not matter at compile time. That's what the runtime cares.

Comment: @Sweeper hmm I think I am misunderstanding the concept of compile time and run time. I thought when the java compiler looks for the method from top down and produces the byte code. Then, jvm uses the byte code and looks for the method bottom up.  So, I am wonder at compile time, y.m() suppose to point to interface Y?

Comment: Yes, bytecode that calls `Y.m()` will be produced, and at runtime that will be dispatched to `B.m()`. Not sure what you mean by "top down" and "bottom up", but I don't see what you are misunderstanding?

Comment: @Sweeper What I meant by top down is looking for the method from parent to child and bottom up is from child to parent. I am just confused what class' method should bytcode target to when run y.m(). Thanks!

Comment: In Java all methods are virtual. That means at runtime Java isn't searching from abstract to concrete (top-down), but from concrete to abstract (bottom-up). If your class A had a method that wasn't overriden by B the runtime would first check if B has an implementation, wouldn't find it and then look at A and executed it. In reality it works a little different, but that is how you can imagine it.

Comment: “Is it interface x method m or interface Y method m?”. There is no such thing as “interface x (nor y) method m”.  Those interfaces simply say that whatever object is being referenced will have a method `void m()`.  That  single  method satisfies both interfaces.  Since class B implements not only Y, but also implicitly X as well, that means even if you had declared `X x = new B(); x.m();`, you would get exactly the same result.  The interfaces specify what methods must exist on the object, but the method actually called will be that of the most   child for that object (regardless of interface)